# lein repl error "Unable to resolve symbol: str in this context"

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm new to clojure. I'm facing below error -

I created a new lein project using command `lein new app clj-lein-app-project`.

The project is on [github](https://github.com/rajcspsg/clj-lein-app-project).

Then I created new namespace `ns-playground.hello` as in [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/clj-lein-app-project/blob/master/src/ns_playground/hello.clj).

The contents of hello.clj is -

```
(ns ns-playground.hello
  (:import [java.util Date]))

(def addition +)

(defn current-date []
  "this function returns the current date"
  (new Date))
```

Then I launched the repl using command `lein repl` -

In repl I did `(str "Hello""""world")` and `(for [el ["element1""element2""element3"]] el)` which are working fine.

Then I changed the namespace to `ns-playground.hello` using command `(in-ns 'ns-playground.hello)`. Now I did `(str "Hello""""world")` and `(for [el ["element1""element2""element3"]] el)` but I got below error -

> Syntax error compiling at (/private/var/folders/7v/gp_j1tf92xx3m8gxltryr_bmzdys_4/T/form-init6109117777235064500.clj:1:1).
>
> Unable to resolve symbol: for in this context

[image]

How the clojure code is not working in different namespace in lein repl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://clojure.org/guides/repl/navigating_namespaces

explains it: If you switch to a namespace, which you previously in your session did not decalred with `(ns ...)`, but instead directly enter to it via `(in-ns ...)` this kind of behavior occurs. You can't then use `clojure.core`'s symbols even.

> What happens if you in-ns to a namespace that has never been created?
> You will see strange things happening. For instance, you will not be
> able to define a function using defn:

```
$ clj Clojure 1.10.0 user=> (in-ns 'myapp.never-created)
#object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x22356acd "myapp.never-created"] myapp.never-created=> (defn say-hello [x] (println "Hello, " x "!"))
Syntax error compiling at (REPL:1:1). Unable to resolve symbol: defn
in this context
```

> Explanation: in this situation, in-ns creates the new namespace and
> switches to it like ns does, but it does a little less work than ns,
> because it does not automatically make available all the names defined
> in clojure.core, such as defn. You can fix that by evaluating
> (clojure.core/refer-clojure):

```
> myapp.never-created=> (clojure.core/refer-clojure) nil
> myapp.never-created=> (defn say-hello [x] (println "Hello, " x "!"))
> #'myapp.never-created/say-hello myapp.never-created=> (say-hello "Jane") Hello,  Jane ! nil
```

> If you only use in-ns to switch to namespaces that have already been
> created, you won’t have to deal with these subtleties.

So either you didn't defined your namespace before entering it.
Or you became a victim of a typo when entering your namespace.

So if you entered a typo-namespace but are too lazy to correct the typo, then just refer by

```
(clojure.core/refer-clojure)
```

Theoretically, you could always attach `clojure.core/` before every symbol - e.g. `clojure.core/for` then it should work - but maybe this is too tedious.